# iReport / jFreeChart - Combining getItemPaint() override and series colors

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, jfreechart, series

I'm attempting to create a bar chart that needs to use specific series colors for N number of categories and a separate color for 1 other category.  Here is an example:

[image]

In the mockup, Categories 1-3 use a collection of 5 colors to render their series while Category 4 uses a single grey color.  My first approach was to override the getItemPaint() method using a customizer class, but I can only figure out how to define a color on the category level, not the series level.  Is it possible to define colors on category and/or series levels?  Something like,

```
If category != "Category4"
    Use colors A, B, C, D, and E in category's series
Else
    Use color F in category's series
```

Another thought I had was to combine iReport's Series Colors bar chart property and the getItemPaint() override; that way I could define the 5 colors to use in iReport and use the getItemPaint() override only in the case where the category equals "Category 4".  So far I've had no luck combining the two; if the override is defined it overrides iReport's Series Color property.

Update with code:

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Paint;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractChartCustomizer;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRChart;

import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;

public class CustomSeriesColors extends JRAbstractChartCustomizer {

    static class CustomRenderer extends BarRenderer {

        private final Paint[] colors1;
        private final Paint[] colors2;

        public CustomRenderer(Paint[] colors1, Paint[] colors2) {
            this.colors1 = colors1;
            this.colors2 = colors2;
        }

        //Set custom colors for series according to category    
        @Override
        public Paint getItemPaint(int row, int column) {
            CategoryDataset l_jfcDataset = getPlot().getDataset();
            String l_rowKey = (String)l_jfcDataset.getRowKey(row);
            String l_colKey = (String)l_jfcDataset.getColumnKey(column);

            if ("Insufficient Data".equalsIgnoreCase(l_colKey)) {
                return this.colors2[row % this.colors1.length];
            } else {
                return this.colors1[row % this.colors1.length];
            }
        }
    }

    public void customize(JFreeChart chart, JRChart jasperChart) {

        // Get plot data.
        CategoryPlot categoryPlot = chart.getCategoryPlot();

        // Define colors to be used by series.
        Color[] color1 = new Color[]{new Color(238,0,0), new Color(255,153,0), new Color(211,190,91), new Color(153,204,102), new Color(0,170,0)};
        Color[] color2 = new Color[]{new Color(200,200,200)};

        // Call CustomRenderer using defined color sets.
        categoryPlot.setRenderer(new CustomRenderer(color1,color2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to write a custom renderer to select a 'Paint'  based on the series and category by overriding `getItemPaint`

```java
@Override
public Paint getItemPaint(int series, int category) {
  if (category == 4)
    return this.colors2[series % this.colors1.length];
  else
    return this.colors1[series % this.colors1.length];
}
```

The use your renderer update for the plot:

```java
Color[] color1 = new Color[]{Color.red, Color.green,Color.blue};
Color[] color2 = new Color[]{Color.gray,Color.gray.darker()};
plot.setRenderer(new CustomRenderer(color1,color2));
```

[image]

Here is the code in full

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Paint;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberTickUnit;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.SymbolAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.BarRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame;
import org.jfree.ui.RefineryUtilities;


public class BarChartDemo7 extends ApplicationFrame {

    static class CustomRenderer extends BarRenderer {

        private final Paint[] colors1;
        private final Paint[] colors2;

        public CustomRenderer(Paint[] colors1,Paint[] colors2) {
            this.colors1 = colors1;
            this.colors2 = colors2;
        }

        @Override
        public Paint getItemPaint(int series, int category) {
            if (category == 4)
                return this.colors2[series % this.colors1.length];
            else
                return this.colors1[series % this.colors1.length];
        }
    }


    public BarChartDemo7(String title) {
        super(title);
        CategoryDataset dataSet=createDataset();
        JFreeChart chart=createChart(dataSet);
        ChartPanel panel=new ChartPanel(chart);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,800));
        setContentPane(panel);
    }


    private static CategoryDataset createDataset() {
        // row keys...
        final String series1 = "ABC";
        final String series2 = "XYZ";

        // column keys...
        final String category1 = "A";
        final String category2 = "B";
        final String category3 = "C";
        final String category4 = "D";
        final String category5 = "E";
        final String category6 = "F";

        // create the dataset...
        final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

        dataset.addValue(35, series1, category1);
        dataset.addValue(37, series1, category2);
        dataset.addValue(40, series1, category3);
        dataset.addValue(52, series1, category4);
        dataset.addValue(52, series1, category5);
        dataset.addValue(52, series1, category6);


        dataset.addValue(30, series2, category1);
        dataset.addValue(32, series2, category2);
        dataset.addValue(35, series2, category3);
        dataset.addValue(45, series2, category4);
        dataset.addValue(30, series2, category1);
        dataset.addValue(32, series2, category2);
        dataset.addValue(35, series2, category5);
        dataset.addValue(45, series2, category4);

        return dataset;
    }



    private static JFreeChart createChart(CategoryDataset dataset) {

        // create the chart...
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
            "ABC",             
            "",                      
            "",                         
            dataset,                         
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,        
            true,                            
            true,                            
            false                            
        );

        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.WHITE);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLACK);

        //Provide a new Symbol Axis
        String[] grade =  new String[101];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < grade.length ; i ++){
            grade[i] = Integer.toString(i);
        }
        grade[0] = "Poor    0";
        grade[50] = "Avg.   50";
        grade[100] = "Best   100";
        SymbolAxis rangeAxis = new SymbolAxis("", grade);
        rangeAxis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(10));
        rangeAxis.setAutoRange(false);
        rangeAxis.setRange(0, 100);
        plot.setRangeAxis(rangeAxis);


        Color[] color1 = new Color[]{Color.red, Color.green,Color.blue};
        Color[] color2 = new Color[]{Color.gray,Color.gray.darker()};
        plot.setRenderer(new CustomRenderer(color1,color2));
        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BarChartDemo7 demo = new BarChartDemo7("ABC");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the updates to the BarRender class compatible with JRAbstractCharCustomizer?  Please excuse my ignorance; I'm very rusty with Java and am working with code written by a previous developer.  One thing I'm unsure of is how to update the class the plot method calls.  The current customizer class (which works as-is, but doesn't have the custom color render) doesn't specify a plot method.  I've updated my question above with my interpretation of your code embedded in my current code.  Does it look off?

Comment: I'm away from my computer now but that looks OK. You don't need to subclass customs renderer after category plot

Comment: So I can drop `(new CustomRenderer()` from `categoryPlot.setRenderer()`?  categoryPlot will know to render from the new CustomRenderer class and not the default BarRenderer class?

Comment: No, but you don't need {} after it. It doesn't do anything as it has no code inside the {}.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks for all of your help.  Looks like Jasper is going to force me to dust off my old Java knowledge, ha.

For those interested, I've updated the code in my question with the completed version.